# After getting rid of cocoapods, I get an error about references to pods still being present

Tags: ios, ios7, cocoapods

When building, I get this error:

```
/Users/alexgenadinik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Marketing-akudmwjaqoqngcgmfqqnygpscroj/Build/Intermediates/Marketing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Marketing.build/Script-99A4E58F6D8E4565916AF78B.sh: line 2: /Users/alexgenadinik/Desktop/Marketing/Pods/Pods-resources.sh: No such file or directory
```

I went into this file: Script-99A4E58F6D8E4565916AF78B.sh and deleted the references to the pods, but I think it gets auto-generated so it keeps getting re-created.

Would anyone know how to prevent it from getting regenerated? Where might the setting for this be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this SO post: [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)  unless you remove the Cocoapods from the workspace entirely, it will still try and run it's scripts.