# cocoapods: The resources are not copied to mainBundle

Tags: embedded-resource, nib, cocoapods, resourcebundle, nswindowcontroller

**I am struggling with resources.** I want to be able to put a `nib` in my pod. One of the classes uses this `nib`.

Here is the podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "MyCBD_BSManagedDocument"

  s.requires_arc = true
  s.osx.platform   = :osx, '10.7'

  s.subspec 'MyCBD_BSManagedDocument' do |ss|
    ss.source_files = 'Classes/MyCBD_BSManagedDocument/**/*.{h,m}'
  end

  s.subspec 'Auxiliary classes' do |ss|

    ss.subspec 'MyCBDLockManager' do |sss|
      sss.source_files = 'Classes/Auxiliary classes/MyCBDLockManager/**/*.{h,m}'
      sss.resource_bundle = {'MyCBDLockManager' => 'Classes/Auxiliary classes/MyCBDLockManager/MyCBDLockManager.xib'}
    end

    ss.subspec 'MyCBDSafeguardManager' do |sss|
      sss.source_files = 'Classes/Auxiliary classes/MyCBDSafeguardManager/**/*.{h,m}'
    end
  end

end
```

Very strangely, in my toy-project to test the pod, it works (I can check the `nib` is in the `mainBundle`), but in my real project, the nib is not in the mainBundle, and I have the error

```
-[MyCBDLockManager loadWindow]: failed to load window nib file 'MyCBDLockManager'.
```

Any advice on how to include resources with cocoa pods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, one phase in the build phases was missing. I don't know why, though. 
So, I had to add this phase again with `pod install`.

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, and `pod install` didn't fix that. Until I've noticed that all the required build phases are present in test target. The issue was that since Cocoa Pods 1.0 there were changes. The core issue was that now it is required to specify explicit real target, otherwise it will choose the first one (in my case it was test target somehow). For more details see http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0-Migration-Guide/

Answer (score 1):

If that phase is missing you should try to run `pod install` again and make sure you're opening the `xcworkspace` that is generated. Also you want just [`resources`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resources) not `resource_bundles` for a single `xib` like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually did `pod install` again but it is not working.

Comment: You can remake the build phase yourself as shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. But still I wonder why it was not here!

Comment: You can follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project/16427883#16427883) and then do another `pod install`.