# Downgrading from CocoaPods 0.35.0 to 0.33.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I need to downgrade CocoaPods from 0.35.0 to 0.33.1. However, I'm running into problems.

**The Situation**

It seems during the upgrade from 0.33.1 to 0.35.0, CocoaPods does the following:

- Remove the pressumably obsolete `Pods.xcconfig` file.
- Add the files `Pods.debug.xcconfig`, `Pods.release.xcconfig`, etc.
- Remove the presence of `Pods.xcconfig` from my `project.pbxproj`.
- Record the presence of `Pods.debug.xcconfig` etc in my `project.pbxproject`.

To downgrade the CocoaPods project from 0.35.0 to 0.33.1, I removed the `Podfile.lock` and `Pods/` folder from my project and did a fresh `pod install`.

CocoaPods successfully creates `Pods.xcconfig`. However, my `project.pbxproj` file is untouched. My project doesn't know about the presence of `Pods.xcconfig`, hence it no longer compiles. The records for `Pods.debug.xcconfig` etc are still there, even though it is not used in CocoaPods 0.33.1.

**The Questions**

1. How can I tell my Xcode project to use `Pods.xcconfig`?
2. How can I tell my Xcode project that I no longer use `Pods.debug.xcconfig` etc?
3. Is there a known procedure to gracefully downgrade the CocoaPods version of a project?

Thanks!

Comment: What issues are you having with CocoaPods 0.35?

Comment: It's not a Cocoapods 0.35.0 problem per se, but rather a bureaucratic issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet to do this would be to entirely remove CocoaPods from your project ([as I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427883/902968)) and then run `pod install` with the older version.

On a sidenote to this, downgrading versions of CocoaPods is a bad idea. Before CocoaPods hits 1.0 any breaking changes can be made that may make working with your old version and the [specs repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) impossible (without cloning an old unsupported version and maintaining it yourself). As you can [see now](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/CocoaPods-version.yml#L2) the minimum supported version is `0.32.1`. Obviously that won't be changed just for the fun of it but, if possible, I would recommend that you sort out your issues with the newer versions and try to stay on it.

Comment: Thank you I managed to successfully remove CocoaPods from my project with the cocoapods-deintegrate plugin. I did a fresh install of 0.33.1, fix some configuration and everything is working fine now.

I understand the concern and would raise the issue in my team. Thanks!