# Issue when removing a previously added library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I installed alamofire in my project. Now I would like to remove it. So I removed the lib from the Podfile which is now empty.
Then I launched

```
pod install
```

Now I have 3 error in my project :

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

What should I do?

Comment: what does your podfile look like

Comment: @DanielGalasko, the file is empty

Comment: this should help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, you should remove CocoaPods entirely from you project and just start over. If you follow these steps, you'll certainly be back up and running in no time.

- Run `pod deintegrate`

  - To install, run `sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate`
  - See [this] (https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate) for more info on `deintegrate`
- Run `pod init` (if you deleted your `Podfile`)
- Add all your info back into the `Podfile` minus the library you wanted to remove (if you deleted your `Podfile`)
- Run `pod install`

At this point your project should be back up and running.