# How to remove Cocoa-Pod from project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I don't know how to remove cocoa-pod from my project.

I find, actually, this error:

> /PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o) ld: 64
>   duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1

and:

I have an app with login page, and I want to make the application to work with "Facebook", "Twitter" and "Google Plus" login.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

Comment: @AshishKakkad :  i can not find workspace in my project but in framework add in add others i find workspace  .