# How to correctly uninstall pods?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I had another developer install pods in my application.

I am not sure why I need them, and from reading another thread, it seems that pods are causing some kind of an issue on my app.

What is the safe/proper/good-practice way to uninstall them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

Answer (score 2):

To remove pods completely follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427883/4244501

To uninstall single pods open the podfile. Remove the lines with the pods you don't want anymore and save the file. Open the console, navigate to the directory with the podfile and run `pod install`.

Comment: Thanks - just to clarify, I still want to keep the code that got put inside the pods. I just don't want it to be organized with pods. Do your suggestions still apply to my situation?

Comment: Why not flagging the question as a duplicate instead of answering @FBente ?

Comment: @Genadinik If you uninstall single pods or remove the pods completely the code will be removed. In that case you should follow the individual manual installation steps for every single project you want to integrate.

Comment: @Mihriban Minaz I didn't had enough reputation to flag anything. Maybe you can upvote my answers to help me out in that case. ;)