# Cocoa Pods Removal

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I had a xcode project with cocoa pods integrated but then I deleted it and made a new project with the same name but cocoa pods is still integrated and giving my project errors. How do I fix this?

Comment: cocoapods-deintegrate[https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate#cocoapods-deintegrate] is something you should use.

Comment: Please try running 'pod deintegrate' at the project folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

Answer (score 2):

delete the .lock, the xcworkspace, and the Pods folder, and pod install again

```
sudo rm podfile.lock
sudo rm project.xcworkspace
sudo rm -R Pods
pod install
```

Comment: Its worked. Sometimes this command sudo rm project.xcworkspace not work. So go to your directory and simply delete it.