# Firebase Module install on ios

Tags: ios, firebase

I followed all instructions for integrating the new `firebase` release on `ios`:

1. I downloaded the file `GoogleService-Info.plist` and include it in the project.
2. I installed the framework with cocoapods

The problem is with this line:

```
@import Firebase;
```

Xcode prints this error:

> "Module Firebase not found"

What is the solution?

My code :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@import Firebase

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [FIRApp configure];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code snap here.

Comment: im in objective-c, what im missing?

Comment: Use `#import' instead of `@import`

Comment: @N.Hicheri use this #import <Firebase/Firebase.h>

Comment: Check this [Firebase Doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/setup.html) `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>`

Comment: it is different for the new version of firebase

Comment: Can you please share the link which doc/tutorial you are following?

Comment: Have you opened the workspace and not project?

Comment: when you create a new project and a new application, you found that :

Comment: yes i opened the workspace

Comment: I followed [New Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites) and I'm able to use both `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h> and @import Firebase;`

Comment: Show your pods folder hirarchy in workspace and code where you import the firebase.

Comment: i import the firebase in appdelegate :

Comment: Yes I did the same and it works. Can not say where you missed something without seeing the project. `Show your pods folder hirarchy in workspace`

Comment: the pods folder hirarchy :

Comment: Pods folder  -> Firebase folder
->Headers folder
->Local Podspecs folder
->Manifest.lock
->Pods.xcodeproj
->Target Support Files folder

Comment: this is the link i followed : https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize_firebase_in_your_app

Comment: Dear Engineer not like this. You are showing path I'm asking for folder hierarchy [like this](http://i.imgur.com/lztKcSO.png)

Comment: how can i add an image to show you?

Comment: self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
 how to create proparty in appdelagte @TheTiger

Comment: @N.Hicheri Take a screenshot an upload it on http://imgur.com then share direct link here.

Comment: @N.Hicheri If you able to write `[FIRApp configure];`  it means your framework has imported successfully.

Answer (score 24):

I ended up fixing it by using

`#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>`

instead of

`@import Firebase`

Comment: For me this worked but I had to not use <angled brackets> but instead use "quotes"

Comment: works for me.

cordova platform rm ios and `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>`

Answer (score 13):

Got the same issue on the import.
My target's build settings overrode the 'Header search path' without the '$(inherited)' flag

'pod update' warns you about that.

1. Open your target build settings
   [image: target build settings]

2. In 'Header search paths' add a line containing $(inherited).

It solved the issue for me

Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

Its work for me in this way.

using **FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h**

Try the below code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FIRApp configure];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: for me too. Thanks, mate!

Comment: This worked for me. I am building Cordova app for iOS platform.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above but sadly, nothing worked. 
Clean the build folder, clearing Xcode cache helped me. Try this:

> 1. Quit Xcode.
> 2. Delete project's temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
> 3. Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
> 4. Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
> 5. Run pod install.
> 6. Open the newly created ProjectName.**xcworkspace** file and build.

Pay extensive attention to the 6th step. Open this newly created **xcworkspace**, not xcodeproj.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486792/913601

Comment: I tried everything else on this page, and this is the only thing that worked -- the key for me was removing the entire Pods folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found that the problem was I have three targets in Cocoapods file. And only my main one target has Firebase added. So that when I want to import Firebase to a file that is used in other targets, Xcode gives error and says Module 'Firebase' not found. This is my pods project file. One solution for me is adding Firebase pod to all targets. Or another solution is removing the file from other targets.

```html
def common_pods
  pod 'XXX'
end

target 'myMainProject' do
  common_pods()
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end

target 'myExtention1' do
  common_pods()
end

target 'myextension2' do
  common_pods()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue and found solution in here: [iOS - Firebase error: Use of unresolved identifier FIRApp running supplied code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328508/ios-firebase-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-firapp-running-supplied-code/37329635#37329635)

Doing the following steps on the terminal command line:

1. pod repo update
2. Commented the pod 'Firebase' line from my Podfile
3. pod install (this removed the old Firebase)
4. Added the pod 'Firebase' line again.
5. pod install (added the new Firebase)

2nd and 3rd steps were the key I think, otherwise CocoaPods didn't try to update it. As I said maybe this could've been solved by doing pod update but now I can't go back and try again.

Comment: Someone used your solution -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Fu51jfAxh-E,
But there's a common issue with the first step, when i run it in terminal, it's stuck on: "Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance"

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of [adding the Firebase SDK to your iOS project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup). You can either use CocoaPods, in which case its really important to make sure your pod dependency is in the target you are using. E.g.

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

target 'Target1' do
end
target 'Target2' do
end
```

There are a lot of different ways of configuring targets in CocoaPods, so your Podfile may look different. The important thing is that the target you specify is linked with the pod - in this case I have specified the Analytics pod so its available to all targets, but if I put it just in the Target1 `do...end` block, then it wouldn't be available in Target2.

If you're using the framework integration method, then make sure the libraries are specified in the *Link Binary With Libraries* section of your Build Phases tab. This should happen automatically if you drag them into a Frameworks group in Xcode.

Finally, if that doesn't work, Xcode may have cached something bad. Try opening the *Product* menu, hold down Option and click *Clean build folder*.

Comment: I tried manually linking it under the Build Phases tab and then cleaning the build folder and it still didn't work for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're just using the frameworks that should be sufficient - make sure you have the full set of frameworks required though (which should be all the ones in the directory of the zip for the service you're using)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue stating that **FirebaseMessaging module not found** in header even though I had correct Podfile configuration.

[image: Screenshot 1]

```
Solution is to remove Cocoapods from project and add it again.
```

You can *remove CocoaPods* from project using this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427883/1753005)

Thereafter, you can *add CocoaPods* again using this [link.](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html)

Below is snapshot for Podfile that I have used.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Below snapshot shows log on dependencies that are installed using Pods.

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Can you help out me on this: [Error while installing Firebase via Cocoapods.] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291947/firebase-uploading-file-getting-optional-string-in-filename) ?

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have `$(inherited)` flag in **Target > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths**

If you still have error, go throw these steps :

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Delete project's temp files located at `~/Users/YourUserName/Library(hidden one)/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. Delete `ProjectName.xcworkspace`
4. Backup project's `Podfile` and delete `Podfile.lock` file and Pods folder
5. Run `pod init`
6. Replace your pervious `Podfile` with the new one.
7. Finally run `pod install`

Now open the newly created `ProjectName.xcworkspace` file and build.

If you have problem in finding `DerivedData` location check this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495772/1572408

Answer (score -2):

This is lame but i fixed integration problems by adding the sources to my project instead using pods. I had to manually fix few files too.

Answer (score -4):

update your pods. 
open terminal go to your project directory and type the following command

> pod update