# Firebase module not found "Objective C Project"

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

What I am using: 
CocoaPods 1.0.1
Xcode7.3.1

Read following article:
[How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project/16427883#16427883)

[Firebase Module install on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322473/firebase-module-install-on-ios)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Did everything that I could think of. Firebase module is not found. 
tried @import, #import, #include ...

This is Objective C project. What throw me off is, I ran, compiled and submitted to AppStore a Month ago with Firebase Analytics. 
Now sudden the master is broken for this project. where as I can do everything fine with swift project on same mac.

**Update:** So I have found the Root cause but that is again leading to different kind of problem. 
below is content my PodFile:

```
#Google Services
#all google services are being merged to firebase 
#pod 'Google/AdMob'

#Firebase 
pod 'Firebase' 
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

if I don't use "Use_frameworks!", Firebase and all are not visible. If I do then MBProgress header files are not found. I know you would way I have to use @import MBProgress, I did. When I do it doesn't find module. 
Does anyone had this kind of problem. If yes. How did you manage. I am not finding anything.

Comment: Are you sure that you are opening the *workspace* file, not the *project* file?

Comment: Even in swift also the problem exist.  i Used import Firebase. can any one help here? @johnelemans

Comment: Did end up with a solution here ? @johnelemans

Comment: @RamcharanReddy : No I dint get any answer even from firebase support team. They forward me the link to stackover flow question. When I opened it was this question. so basically they sucks

Comment: @Cœur : Prolly you missed the actual question. but anyway I updated the question.

Comment: @Alix thank you, I retracted the vote.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem, I used as workaround the following code

```
// instead of this:
@import Firebase;

// i use this:
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding Firebase without `Pod` and if you already added the `Firebase.h` file to your Xcode project you can use :

```
#import "Firebase.h"
```