# Firebase uploading file getting optional string in filename

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I was implementing Firebase friendly chat sample while uploading image. Getting response with optional string. what is missed?

```
Optional(FIRStorageMetadata 0x7fc84aced790: {
    bucket = "abc.appspot.com";
    contentEncoding = identity;
    contentType = "image/jpeg";
    downloadTokens = "abctoken";
    generation = 1231231;
    metageneration = 1;
    name = "Optional(\"S5CKnKUykANdxSvZ3wujpMXHTvg1\")/494509700277/asset.JPG";
    timeCreated = "2016-09-02T11:49:00.114Z";
    updated = "2016-09-02T11:49:00.114Z";
})
```

My code:

```
 let filePath = "(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/(Int(NSDate.time‌​IntervalSinceReferen‌​ceDate() * 1000))/(referenceUrl.lastPathComponent!)"
```

was written with optional value (?) in sample so i convert it (!)

Comment: when you set the value in firebase .. at that time you are sending optional value check that twice

Comment: That name was created when you uploaded the file to Firebase Storage. You will need to force-unwrap the optional value there. If you need help with that, post the minimal code that shows how you upload the file to Firebase Storage.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank You. 

let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/\(Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() * 1000))/\(referenceUrl.lastPathComponent!)"

was written with optional value (?) in sample so i convert it (!)

Comment: I added the code to the question itself, where it is a lot more readable. Please check and fix (by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39291947/edit) link) if it's not your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

In swift you must force unwrap value to avoid this (but make sure, it's not nil).

`"\(optionalValue!)"`

Or unwrap it in standard way

```
if let value = optionalValue {
    someFIRMethod("\(value)")
}
```