# Firebase rules (permission denied)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a project in Firebase for practice. Here is what i am doing. I am using Email Authentication and when a person signs up with email and password, my app gets his name and add to the Firebase database with his user id. 
Here is the database in Firebase i set

```
{
"rules": {
"users": {

  "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
    "items": {

      "$item_id": {
        "title": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0"
        }
      }
    },
      "user-details":{
        "name" : {
          ".validate" : "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 0"
        }
      }
  }
},

"all-public" : {
  ".read" : "true",
    ".write" : "true"
}
  }
}
```

And here is the code in swift i wrote.

```
var dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
            dbref.child("users").child("\(user?.uid)").child("user-details").child("name").setValue(name)

            dbref.child("all-public").child((user!.uid)).setValue(name)
```

The data to the second child **all-public** is added successfully but it fails to add the above first child and says permission denied.
Here is what it says in the console.

```
2017-04-09 20:00:02.145 ToDo App[1573] <Warning> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] setValue: or removeValue: at /users/Optional("klvexHq3GOQ4IiWpOs4WP7H4pmy1")/user-details/name failed: permission_denied
2017-04-09 20:00:28.426 ToDo App[1573] <Warning> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] Listener at /users/klvexHq3GOQ4IiWpOs4WP7H4pmy1/items failed: permission_denied
```

First i thought this would be because i am not yet signed in. So i tried signing in immediately after the sign up and then add data to the database but still the same error.
Please help me with this. I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `user` is optional, you need to first extract its value:

```
var dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
if let uid = user?.uid {
  dbref.child("users").child("\(uid)").child("user-details/name").setValue(name)
  dbref.child("all-public").child((uid)).setValue(name)
}
```

See 
[Firebase uploading file getting optional string in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291947/firebase-uploading-file-getting-optional-string-in-filename)

Comment: So, this is not the problem with permissions of my database? Because it says permission denied.

Comment: The database doesn't allow the operation, because your code fails to unwrap the optional value.  If you check the error message carefully you'll see it contains `Optional("klvexHq3GOQ4IiWpOs4WP7H4pmy1")`, which is not the UID of the user.