# How to resolve 'FIRApp' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is definition in module 'FirebaseCore?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Im migrating from xcode 11.7 to xcode 12. I tried building the app from xcode 12 and then these errors showed up. Do you have any solutions? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the solution I found it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41102620/4444250

Solution:

Open the file ios/ProjectName/AppDelegate.m and you need to replace the import

from  @import Firebase

to  #import <Firebase/Firebase.h>