# ionic 2 - Error : Module 'FirebaseInstanceID' not found in ios

Tags: ios, angular, firebase, push-notification, ionic2

I try to build an Ionic 2 app with push notification on iOS.

I had three errors :

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I tried to solve it buy this modification in my [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock to this :

```
diff "${SRCROOT}/Podfile.lock" "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I think it works. But now, I have a new error in xCode after try to run on my device :

```
 Module 'FirebaseInstanceID' not found
```

[image]

I tried to run pod install again but no difference.

But I keep my error. Someone have a solution to solve this ?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: Yes I solved this problem.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343645/firebasemessaging-module-not-found-using-cocoapods-ios