# App crashing "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

So, after 1 hour of googling I still can't fix this error that I got. Whats happening is that every time I go to click my "Sign Up" button, the app crashes, its suppose to redirect me to a different view where the user can sign up with there email and password. I tried many things other users have posted but none of them seem to be working.

error code:

```
2016-11-14 23:30:52.363967 FHCI[4785:1536750] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
2016-11-14 23:30:52.364 FHCI[4785] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
2016-11-14 23:30:53.561590 FHCI[4785:1536709] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Default app has already been configured.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186e4a1c0 0x18588455c 0x186e4a108 0x100107358 0x100107120 0x1000a795c 0x1000a7a40 0x18cca50b0 0x18cca4c78 0x18d668ae4 0x18cfefb08 0x18cff72c4 0x18d010d04 0x18d013e5c 0x18cd97b54 0x18d464b9c 0x18d465d84 0x18d465b8c 0x18d465e5c 0x18ccda484 0x18ccda404 0x18ccc48b8 0x18ccd9cf0 0x18ccd9818 0x18ccd4a60 0x18cca552c 0x18d492a54 0x18d48c4bc 0x186df8278 0x186df7bc0 0x186df57c0 0x186d24048 0x1887aa198 0x18cd102fc 0x18cd0b034 0x1000aa388 0x185d085b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Picture of my code

[image]

Story board

[image]

Comment: You should add the code as a snippet instead of adding it as a photo.

Comment: If none of solutions worked for you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46607974/2149779

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Earlier, I have faced the same issue. Fix it by below solutions.

## Solution:1

> Please make sure `FIRApp.configure()` the statement executes once
>   throughout the project. If you have written more then one time then
>   you have to remove your second unused statement. It will solve your
>   problem.

## Solution:2

> 1 ) Remove pod file from project ([How to remove pod file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project))
>
> 2 ) Remove Old `GoogleService-Info` file from the project.
>
> 3 ) Download `GoogleService-Info` and add it into the project.
>
> 4 ) Add `pods` file Again.
>
> 5) Put the Below method in `Appdelegate` file.

```
override init() {
   super.init()
   FIRApp.configure()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem. In my case the file **GoogleService-Info.plist** was not included in **Copy Bundle Resources**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error the solution above didn't work for me.

**Solution:**

Just go to status bar of *Xcode Product* ⇒ *clean*

**Image:**

[image: Open product tab dropdown with clean item selected]

Comment: Please check the image you linked - seems to be a broken link. Also please possibly embed it directly in answer.

Comment: The link is fine, I wanted to show just that. I added the solution in answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. I embedded the image for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I removed `Main.storyboard` but forgot to remove in from General target's settings. Removing it solved unexpected crash on app launch.