# Firebase causing "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I started a blank Xcode project and all I did was add the Firebase framework via Cocoapods and import in the Appdelegate and viewcontroller. When I add **FIRApp.configure()** to **didFinishLoadingWithOptions** I get that error. If I remove that line but still have the framework imported it runs with no errors. This happens on a blank project with nothing in the storyboard nor viewcontroller.swift.

In the console it says libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(11db)

Xcode 8.2, swift 3

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
 FIRApp.configure()

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

Podfile

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your        project
    # platform :ios, '9.0'

    target 'dur2' do
      # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
      use_frameworks!

      # Pods for dur2

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Invites'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig' 
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

end

Comment: Did you add the googleplist file?

Comment: Did you add the .plist file for Firebase?

Comment: is the file added to the right target?

Comment: and did you import Firebase in the file?

Comment: Yes it's added to the right target @ro4ch

Comment: Yeah Firebase is imported in that file. It runs fine until it add FIRApp.configure() @NathanLevitt

Comment: Can you post your file's code please

Comment: Added, theres only 2 things I added to the file since creating it (import firebase and FIRapp.configure()  ). @NathanLevitt

Comment: Make sure you are working in the .xcworkspace when you build your project

Comment: Your cocoapods needs to be updated. I ran into the same thing the other day. Try a /sudo gem install cocoapods and then a pod install. If that doesn't work, post your Podfile so we can take a look.

Comment: I am using the .xcworkspace @NathanLevitt

Comment: I updated my cocoa pods but still get the error. I added my pod file to my question @Jay

Comment: OK. I created a new project and followed the instructions on the Firebase Getting Started guide, adding the podfile and it worked. So... something else must be causing the. Issue. Can you please create a new project and walk through the guide [Add Firebase to iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Comment: Okay I created a new project added Firebase and still get the same error. Here's what I did. 1.create a new project in Firebase and get plist file. 2.drag and drop plist file into Xcode project below the existing info.plist 3.close Xcode and pod init, edit pod file then pod install in terminal for that project. 4. Open .xcworkspace and import Firebase in Appdelegate and add FIRApp.configure() 5. Run in simulator . I followed the the website exactly and still get the error. Any idea what I could be doing wrong or a possible cause? @Jay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try a test.

Create a new project following the instructions on the Firebase website, ensuring you add the GoogleService-Info.plist to your project.

At the step where you create a pod file, make sure you are in your projects folder and use this text:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'your-project-name' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Firesearch
  pod ‘Firebase/Core’
end
```

and put your project name in place of *your-project-name*

Save the file and then do a

```
pod install
```

Then open the project-name.xcworkspace and build it.

Comment: Okay I did that and ran it on my device and no errors came up, my Firebase console confirms an app install. From this I can only think that the additional pods I installed caused the error, any ideas?

Comment: How can I remove the additional pods that I installed with my previous project?

Comment: @Henry Well, you can try the [Automated App](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) that may help. Other than that they have to be manually removed. You can also try removing the pod from your podfile, then run pod install again.

Answer (score 3):

**Worked for Xcode 9**

If none of solutions worked for you try this:

1. Close Xcode
2. In Finder:

   - Remove *.xcworkspace* file
   - Remove *Podfile.lock* file
   - Remove *Pods* folder
3. In Terminal (in project folder): *pod install*
4. Make sure that *GoogleService-Info.plist* is added to your target and generated for your BUNDLE_ID.

For unknown reasons when you use both **"Firebase/Admob"** and **"Firebase/Core"** pods Xcode can mess up the workspace and produce a bad build that will crash at runtime if you try to call **FirebaseApp.configure()** or **GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "APP_ID")**

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet,

Go to your project in firebase and download the google.plist file and add it to your project and run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using another gmail account. Create a new project on firebase then create a data base and add your ios app to the firebase database (Make sure that GoogleService-Info.plist is added to your target and generated for your BUNDLE_ID.)

Answer (score 1):

I've been pulling my hair for 2 days...

here is what I found

1. make sure you have the right GoogleService-info.plist file
   enable the .plist file.
2. point the file to your target app 
   [plist target to your app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE2vI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying *GoogleService-Info.plist* to your project, just drag and drop *GoogleService-Info.plist* to ios/appName, then check the copy if needed option.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4 and Xcode 10:

Delete the XC workspace, podfile.lock, podfile and the pod folder. Then re-do the pod install and start with your new XC workspace.