# Missing file Parse/PFNullability.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

Today is the last day to migrate my iOS application off of Parse.com to my new server. I have everything setup, except now when I tried adding the new Frameworks to my xcode project I keep getting the error:

> Parse/PFNullability.h not found

I have been searching for solutions to this for hours and still no luck, I installed all the new frameworks with cocoa pods and I don't know what else to try. Thanks again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Ya I did I'll post the answer, forgot about this thread haha.

Answer (score 0):

I spent countless hours removing the old frameworks and trying to add the new ones by dragging and dropping into the project and also using cocoa pods, which resulted in an endless game of whack a mole for missing files...

The solution was to completely remove all the dependencies like Parse, Bolts, Facebook, etc. Then clean the project, and also clean the build folder. Close the project entirely. Remove all the cocoa pods stuff as well. Re clean everything just to be safe. Then only add the frameworks with cocoa pods.

For some reason having a mix of cocoa pods and libraries linked the traditional way meant that dependencies in the cocoa pods didn't have access to libraries in my main project folder. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've deleted all frameworks and pods, cleaned the project and added pods. And keep getting "Bridging-Header.h:13:9: 'Parse/PFNullability.h' file not found". So frustrating!!!

Comment: Did you follow these steps for removing the podfiles? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project