# Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9-beta, xcode9

Apparently I have managed to build my project in Xcode 9 beta and now I only get the error

> Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.1

When I run the project in Xcode 8. The module in my case are Alamofire. I have tried to restart Xcode but nothing happens any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Note: had same issue and Clean & Rebuild my project fixed the problem, I didn't have to edit Podfile

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two options that you can do:
`Clean` the project and then try to `re-build` your solution and see if it works.

If it don´t work and you still get the same error message then do the following steps and it should work for you:

1. Open your `podfile` and remove `Alamofire`
2. Run `pod update`
3. Re-add `Alamofire` to your `podfile`
4. Run `pod update`
5. When this is done, `clean` your project and run it

Comment: Same problem here but using Carthage. Trying all the tricks I know to clean project and the problem still here. Any idea how to solve it for Carthage?

Comment: followed the steps, but unfortunately didn't work. Interesting fact is that it works on the simulator (same iPad version as hardware version) without a problem, but on preparing for the hardware iPad it shows this error (Alamofire 4.5.1)

Comment: @Heki, try to remove the app from your device and reinstall it and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Rashwan L, unfortunately the app never made it to the device so I cannot remove it. The build failes

Answer (score 19):

Same problem here but using Carthage. And here is the answer:

- `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData`
- delete the `Carthage` folder for the project
- Update Carthage: `carthage update --platform iOS`

And voilà!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and cleaning the build folder helped:

```
Command+Option+Shift+K
```

or

`Product` -> `Option+Clean`

Answer (score 2):

Just deleting Derived data worked for me, no need to do Pod install again

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem in a project where dependency is managed by Carthage. In my case, I didn't set command line tool in xcode (Type in xcodebuild -version, you will know whether you set it up or not), so first step is to go to XCode --> Preference --> Locations then select the xcode you want to serve as command line tool. Then you can follow the steps that @Domsware mentioned above to rebuild all frameworks you are gonna use.

===============================================

Same problem here but using Carthage. And here is the answer:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData
delete the Carthage folder for the project
Update Carthage: carthage update --platform iOS
```

===============================================

Then don't forget to delete old links under 'Linked frameworks and libraries' and drag all frameworks from /Carthage folder under you project to 'Linked frameworks and libraries'.

Then voilà!

For those who are using CocoaPods, I suspect (Disclaimer: I didn't encounter this problem in project where CocoaPods is the dependency manager) the solution would be run the following command in terminal:

```
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ pod install
```

where you might need to install 'deintegrate' and 'clean' tool for CocoaPod

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
```

more details see post 
[How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines at the end of your pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
    print "Setting the default SWIFT_VERSION to 4.0\n"
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['SomeTarget-iOS', 'SomeTarget-watchOS'].include? "#{target}"
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to 3.0\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        else
            print "Setting #{target}'s SWIFT_VERSION to Undefined (Xcode will automatically resolve)\n"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings.delete('SWIFT_VERSION')
            end
        end
    end
end
```