# Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.1 — Carthage

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage, xcode9-beta

I wanted to test my app using Xcode 9 beta. Now I am back to Xcode 8 and I have the following error:

`Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.1`

To solve this error I refresh all Carthage build and made some cleaning:

- removed all Carthage `build` and `checkout`
- removed `Derived Data` directory
- cleaned the project
- run carthage update

But the error still here.

### Carthage

The command used is: 'carthage update --platform iOS'

As the problem lie on always the same framework, `DeviceKit` I then manage to remove it from `Cartfile`.

Project build then show errors as `DeviceKit` is not found.
I then re-add it to `Cartfile` and run `carthage update DeviceKit  --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`

### And the error re-appear.

This related question bring answer but for Cocoapods: [Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44475274/540780)

Comment: Specifically what command did you use for `Carthage` to update?

Comment: `carthage update    --platform iOS`

Comment: Maybe try `carthage update NameOfTheLibrary --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`. Also make sure you've switched the command-line tools back to the Xcode 8 version : `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Already done this. I update my question to add these steps.

Comment: My only other immediate suggestions would be to use `TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3_1 carthage bootstrap`, and perhaps remove/recreate `Cartfile.resolved` if that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you upgrade to Swift 4.0 when you opened up Xcode 9? Do you have a backup? Otherwise, while I feel for you - I think your options are very limited.

Comment: @dfd No, I did not update to Swift ' on Xcode 9. And yes I have a backup.

Comment: @l'L'l What does the "TOOLCHAINS..." command do?

Comment: @Domsware: It allows you to choose which toolchain version of swift to use for `carthage bootstrap`.

Comment: @l'L'l OK. Thank you

Comment: @l'L'l Problem not solved after using the TOOLCHAINS... command...

Comment: Problem solved by cleaning Carthage' derived data. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Solved by the following steps:

- delete some Derived Data for *Carthage*: `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData`
- delete the *Carthage* folder for your project
- Update *Carthage*:  `carthage update --platform iOS`

I found the answer on the dedicated *Carthage*' page on GitHub: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2062