# Cocoa Pod File In Red

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Does anyone know why in the navigator of my Xcode project my Pods.xcodeproj file is listed in red? I am assuming that means Xcode cannot find the file so how do I make sure it actually does exist in the project.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to update your pods

Comment: its showing red b'coz it is not found by Xcode so try to remove and add again pods.

Comment: What @RichardG said. You could try to clean an re-build you project or more specifically change your build target to your Pods-projectname and do a Clean & Build.

Comment: @RichardG feel like helping a nooby out? And showing me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

run **pod install** in your workspace directory. It will install all the dependencies for you.

Comment: when I go to the directory and punch in pod init it says no Xcode project found, please specify one. Any idea why?

Comment: Please check location for podfile & do pod init on same location.

Comment: so I'm clicking show in finder on the pods from Xcode and I'm still getting that error in terminal when I type pod init

Answer (score 0):

Do the usual Xcode fix stuff e.g. delete derived data and clean the project. Then, in Terminal, go to the directory that contains your `Podfile`. Once there, run these commands:

```
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install cocoa pods on your Mac. For that you need to go [cocoapods.org](https://cocoapods.org/)

If you want to uninstall cocoa pods then refer [this ans.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

So first remove cocoa pods from your project and then install again.

Make sure you open workspace `.xcworkspace` not `.xcodeproj` project file.

Comment: Alright I think I installed the pods correctly. But now when I try to run the program I get an error saying: "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). You know why that might be happening? 
Thanks so much for all the help Richard