# Receive Clang error message exit with code 1 when building/Archiving Project

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, uikit

Whenever I'm getting ready to archive my project and build it to see if everything is ok. I get an error message. I tried to look it up but the solutions did not work for me. can someone please help me?

I am using cocoapods on my project. (I thought it had something to do with PCLBlurEffectAlert and so I deleted the framework from the pods section but I still get the error message.)

[image]

You can click on the image to make it bigger so you can see it.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Have you tried by removing cocoa pod completely with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project and add it again?

Comment: PCLBlurEffectAlert is not being included in your binary, you need to check your build settings