# Xcode build failure diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode

Using Xcode 9.2. I ran **Pod install** in root directory and did a clean  and Build but still issue remains. I even deleted the podfile, Manifestfile. Lock files and ran POD Install in root directly and did clean and Build but issue still remains same.Any  suggestion to this problem to this solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or 
update your CocoaPods installation.
```

Comment: did you try deleting the Podfile.lock and then running Pod install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean / deintregate?

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ rm Podfile
```

See also: [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

Comment: Thank you for  your  suggestion. No I haven't tried this. I will update if this solution works.