# ld: library not found for -lreact-native-fetch-blob with pods?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-fetch-blob

I just finished working with android and moved on to Xcode and it's been pretty challenging to work with. I am also unfamiliar with pods, but I know that when I installed them I got this from the log:

```
    Fetching podspec for `RNVectorIcons` from `../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-fetch-blob` from `../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob`
Downloading dependencies
Installing QBImagePickerController (3.4.0)
Using RNVectorIcons (4.5.0)
Installing RSKImageCropper (2.1.0)
Installing React (0.11.0)
Using react-native-fetch-blob (0.10.6)
```

I read that since I have pods with `fetch-blob` I don't need to use .xcodeproj, instead use .xcworkspace. I deleted the .xcodeproj from the side panel and removed the `.a` from the Link Binary With Libraries. How do I know if I am using .xcworkspace?

Here is the error:

```
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/laneyw/Desktop/ReactProjects/exampleapp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/laneyw/Desktop/ReactProjects/exampleapp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/laneyw/Desktop/ReactProjects/exampleapp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-fetch-blob'
ld: library not found for -lreact-native-fetch-blob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right when you open xcode click 'Open another project' and then navigate to your .xcworkspace file in finder [image]

In my case the blue with white 'A' is the xcodeproj and the white with blue 'A' is the .xcworkspace

Comment: Thank you. But where would I find `react-native-fetch-blob`'s .xcworkspace? And how would this get rid of the error?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed your one question "How do I know if I am using .xcworkspace?" I used this to set up cocoapods https://shift.infinite.red/beginner-s-guide-to-using-cocoapods-with-react-native-46cb4d372995 and let me tell you. If you can avoid using cocoapods DO IT! Pods are a problem you just don't need to have. I was using fetch-blob without pods but added it for a mixpanel library. Sorry I can't be of much help with specifics. I battled red screens for days getting my project to work with cocoapods and I expect you'll do the same. Back out now if you can.

Comment: Ok gotcha. I'll stop using pods because I am starting to see the problems honestly. I have one more question though. Is it possible to uninstall it and remove packages from it so that I can stick to manually linking?

Comment: Good idea to save yourself the headache. As for how to remove it from your project, I would direct you to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project