# how to properly install "RxSwift" module?

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift

I'm trying to build a project that uses RxSwift module, XCode keeps complaining with the error "no such module RxSwift"...

I've tried to install this module several times, in the terminal I got the following message after `pod install`

```
    Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using RxCocoa (4.3.1)
Using RxSwift (4.3.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `11.4` on target `BTCPrice` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `watchos` with version `4.3` on target `WatchApp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `watchos` with version `4.3` on target `WatchApp Extension` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] The `BTCPriceTests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-BTCPriceTests/Pods-BTCPriceTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `BTCPriceTests [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-BTCPriceTests/Pods-BTCPriceTests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

as I could understand it RxSwift was installed, why does Xcode keep complaining about it?

I'm executing the .xcworkspace file..

thank you in advance for the answers!

Comment: Right so that should have added RxSwift to your workspace but have you added the RxSwift framework to the target of your actual project (i.e. as an embedded binary and/or linked framework)?

Comment: I suggest you do the things the pod tool suggests.

Answer (score 0):

[How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project/32921657#32921657)

Simple Steps to installed pod file:

**Close project of Xcode**

1.Open terminal (Command + Space  & type terminal)

2.Set your project path on terminal.(cd Desktop/PodDemos)

3.Type command on terminal: **sudo gem install cocoapods**

4.Command : **pod init**

5.Go to pod file of your project and adding pod which you want to install(**Command: open podfile**)

6.Added in pod file : **pod 'RxSwift'**

**pod 'RxCocoa'**

7.Command : **Pod install**

8.open your Project from terminals
Command : open PodDemos.xcworkspace

**OR**

Go to project folder and open PodDemos.xcworkspace