# Cocoapods: how to delete one pod manually?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

How to delete one pod manually with Cocoapods in Xcode?

I knew `pod deintegrate`, I have seen [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

It is too hard for me. Need more details, or a tutorial.

---

#### The reason of doing it:

I take part in an old, massive project.There are thousands of warnings there . So I want to maintain a personal version of the project.

When starting to delete one pod ,failed after running `pod install`

the warnings:

```
term pod install                                
Analyzing dependencies
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.5.0) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.4.0). Incompatibility issues may arise.
Cloning spec repo `z-appplatform-zspecs` from `http://git.zsys.com/AppPlatform/zSpecs.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `http://git.zsys.com/AppPlatform/zSpecs.git` named `z-appplatform-zspecs`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

[!] Smart quotes were detected and ignored in your Podfile. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.
```

The remote repos are of my company's server, I need authorization (secret).

After a lot of communication with my leader, he said "The pods don't need to update. And he can't give me the authorization to remote repo, he will manually do it for me"

Not convenient, with trying a lot to improve a massive project.

Comment: just remove that pod name in your pod file and in terminal start pod install command

Comment: One of the pod repo is `http:git.z.corp.com/z.git`, I don't have the authorization