# Build error after deintegrating Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I followed the following guide: [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project) because my podfile was giving me a lot of trouble. Now I'm getting this error message and have no idea what's going on

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTLinkingManager in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTLinkingManager in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
      +[RCTLinkingManager load] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTErrorUnspecified", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager openURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTRunningInAppExtension", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager canOpenURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTSharedApplication", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager openURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
      -[RCTLinkingManager canOpenURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTLinkingManager in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTLinkingManager in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
      +[RCTLinkingManager load] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTErrorUnspecified", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager openURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTRunningInAppExtension", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager canOpenURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTSharedApplication", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager openURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
      -[RCTLinkingManager canOpenURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Simply clean your DerivedData.

Comment: That didn't fix it. Anything else I could try?

Comment: (1) Create a new project. (2) `pod init`. (3) `pod install`. (4) `pod deintegrate` => no error, which means your question is lacking [mcve].