# Error : The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am not using Pods. But accidentally I installed it and deleted all folders from my project repo.
After that , when compiling shows this error message. 
I searched  podfile.lock file in my project folder but cannot find. 
Then why such error
Help me to solve it.

Comment: Search for `Podfile` in your project. And try running `pod install` in your terminal.

Comment: I don't want to use pods anymore. So why I should install it again ?

Comment: Are you opening the `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

Comment: See the answers on that suggested duplicate above, short version: you need to run `pod clean` and `pod deintegrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably some CocoaPods related files and rules left over. You can use the `pod deintegrate` command to remove CocoaPods from your project. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_deintegrate

Make sure you have your project in version control or backed up before doing this, so if something goes wrong you can always roll back.