# XCode project build fail: x duplicate symbols for architecure x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have come across this issue frequently when manipulating the pod file of my xcode project.

Wether I am adding a few pods or just a single one, this error seems to persist. When searching I mostly found that I had to run

```
pod install
```

or

```
pod update "some pod"
```

Both of these suggestions did not fix the issue even though when reading the documentation for pod update, it seems to be the exact command necessary.

```
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::FilterPolicy::~FilterPolicy()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 5.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::FilterPolicy::~FilterPolicy()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 5.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::FilterPolicy::~FilterPolicy()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 5.o
duplicate symbol 'vtable for leveldb::FilterPolicy' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 5.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo name for leveldb::FilterPolicy' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 5.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo for leveldb::FilterPolicy' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 5.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::FilterPolicy::~FilterPolicy()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::FilterPolicy::~FilterPolicy()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::FilterPolicy::~FilterPolicy()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy.o
duplicate symbol 'vtable for leveldb::FilterPolicy' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo name for leveldb::FilterPolicy' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo for leveldb::FilterPolicy' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/filter_policy.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::Options::Options()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options 5.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::Options::Options()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options 5.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::Options::Options()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options.o
duplicate symbol 'leveldb::Options::Options()' in:
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options 4.o
    /Users/garrettohara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bucket-disikvjcqullzqachvszkwdlviwd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/options.o
ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue all you have to do is

```
cat podfile
```

Make sure that all your pods are within the file, then

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Comment: for a more indepth analysis of managing pods and how to properly remove all pods from your xcode project please read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project