# Get error while install alamofire pod in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

recently I install the alamofire  and GooglePlaces pod in my swift project for google autocomplete places in my application and I get the error that is -

The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.

[image]

Comment: What's your "XCode version", it should defines which Swift version it supports. Since I guess you didn't defined a specific version for Alamofire, get the version that's compatible with your Swift version.

Comment: @Larme Xcode version is 9  - "when I set the swift version 3.2 or 4.0 for Alamofire it gives me multiple errors approx 70 errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
Remove all pods from your project, [--no-integrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project),
Now change your swift version (like 4.2),
Add the pod and install.

Comment: remove cocoa pods? or remove alamofire pods