# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 under Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I now have the same question with above title but have not found the right answer yet. I got the error:

```
    /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboSDK-Client-cgodalyxmwqzynaxfbbewrooymnq/Build/Intermediates/TestMoboSDK-Client.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboSDK-Client.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MoboSDK.o
    /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboSDK-Client-cgodalyxmwqzynaxfbbewrooymnq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMoboSDK.a(MoboSDK.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MoboSDK in:
    /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboSDK-Client-cgodalyxmwqzynaxfbbewrooymnq/Build/Intermediates/TestMoboSDK-Client.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestMoboSDK-Client.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MoboSDK.o
    /Users/nle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMoboSDK-Client-cgodalyxmwqzynaxfbbewrooymnq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMoboSDK.a(MoboSDK.o)
ld: 75 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Finally** I find out the reason of this error cause I added `-ObjC` to the `Other Linker Flags`. After remove this value then I can build my project successfully, but I don't know why. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: The linker has encountered symbols defined more than once - 75, to be exact. This is likely because you `#include`'d or `#import`'d something (likely the MoboSDK, whatever that is) more than once.

Comment: this error happen after I add `GoogleConversionTrackingSDK-iOS-3.0` into my project.Before that, it's work ok.I also tried to remove it, but the error still happen.

Comment: it's not your case, cause before I add the sdk of google my project build ok.

Comment: Second answer from Adam Waite is really straight forward. Make sure there is no .m file #imported somewhere.

Comment: In my case I was trying to use same string array name in two separate classes. When I have changed the array  name in one of the classes this error has been removed.

Comment: Make sure you #include a .h file, not a .m.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42089897/3024579

Comment: A very similar error is thrown by accidentally including a `.cpp` file instead of it's corresponding header file `.hpp`!

Comment: I have tried most of the suggested solutions below but I still have the error, can anyone please help. 

1. I didn't find any duplicate files at Targets > Build Phases > Compile Sources 
2. I changed the No Common Data to No, not working
3. I deleted all the derived data, clean and rebuild, Failed. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669403/1-duplicate-symbol-for-architecture-x86-64?noredirect=1#comment86478950_49669403

Comment: Worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 131, accepted):

> 75 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Means that you have loaded same functions twice. 
As the issue disappear after removing  `-ObjC` from `Other Linker Flags,` 
this means that this option result that functions loads twice:

from Technical Q&A

> This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library
>   that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will
>   typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code
>   loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of
>   effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on
>   existing classes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Comment: In other words, make sure you remove any object files in your xcode project.

Comment: It also work for me too, but my other libraries are depends on `-ObjC` flag. So I must need to keep this flag in my project settings. So could you please suggest any other solution?

Comment: I guess you need to review all your libraries: If you get duplicate linker error, that means you have same source code in 2 or more libraries.

Comment: I had to remove some of the React libraries it was complaining about under Target->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries in Xcode since it was conflicting with my cocoa pods install of React

Comment: In my case I have import .m file. So stupid mistake. Once I imported .h file. It is ready for build!! Thanks

Answer (score 292):

For me, changing 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No ( under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation ) fixed the problem.

Comment: This solved my problem. Is it ever require to change it back to `NO` ? What's the reason behind this ?

Comment: If I were writing functional code in Swift I wouldn't want any common blocks of code, but writing OOP/MVC code in ObjC sometimes it makes sense to have duplicated blocks ( I have both metric and imperial functions that calculate similar things in many of my fitness apps )

Comment: Yes this solves the problem, but not the reason behind it. If you defined a const, make sure that definiton is ok. In my case I simply forgot "extern". This is mentioned in Sauvik Dolui answer.

Comment: Xcode 8 prompted this change as one of its automatic updates and broke my build :/

Comment: Xcode 9 automatically changed it in automatic update of an old project. Restored to "NO" and build succeeded.

Comment: This works, but I had to change it in target and project

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: In xcode 10 it's now under Apple Clang - Code Generation
Thanks !

Answer (score 269):

Stupid one, but make sure you haven't `#import`ed a `.m` file by mistake somewhere

Comment: I hadn't done this, but this solution helped me find what I had done which was to declare a variable outside the @interface block in a .h file by mistake.

Comment: When using unit tests, only the .m file is generated. I created a header file for it despite i guess this is not the best solution - i wanted to create a base test class.

Comment: Thank you so much for enlightening my mind for the possibility that I made such a stupid mistake.

Comment: how about cross-project import .m file?

Comment: Just need to import `.h` file 

Comment: I tried switching the build setting flag, didn't work. I tried creating a new header file, importing the .h instead of .m, and placing the contents of my .m file inside the header file and it worked.

Answer (score 67):

In my case, I just created a header file to define constant strings like this:

```objectivec
NSString *const AppDescriptionString = @"Healthy is the best way to keep fit";
```

I solved this scenario by using `static`:

```
static NSString *const AppDescriptionString = @"Healthy is the best way to keep fit";
```

Comment: this solved the issue for me. Although i prefixed `extern` instead of `static` : `extern NSString * const kNotificationName;`. Which is strange, because u usually did not add such prefix, and it worked fine..

Comment: This, for some reason, solved my issue. Thanks. I don't understand why the compiler couldn't give out a better response than duplicate symbols, which doesn't seem related at all.

Comment: @Sirens, I also expected a better error message from the LLVM compiler. Anyway I was lucky enough to find out the error after 2 days. :(

Comment: this was my problem as  well why is the actual problem caused by this?

Comment: This is fine if all the variables in `AppStrings.h` are constants, however it will cause havok if you want a global mutable variable as every source file that includes the header file will have their own copy of the variable.  It's a bad solution.

Comment: @user1244109 `static` is for when you actually have a value (`static NSString * kFoo = @"Foo";`) and `extern` is for when you are just saying "this constant exists but its value is defined in the `.m`/`.c`/etc. (`extern NSString * kFoo;`). Also, I recommend using `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` because it adapts to different compilation environments (ObjC, ObjC++, Win32, etc.)

Answer (score 37):

Happens also when you declare const variables with same name in different class:

in file Message.m

```
const int kMessageLength = 36;

@implementation Message

@end
```

in file Chat.m

```
const int kMessageLength = 20;

@implementation Chat

@end
```

Comment: Not const but it worked for me when I change variable name

Comment: I had this with a pointer of my own class variable defined in the @implementation of two different classes

Comment: At compile time, compiler checks for duplicate symbols (here global variables) only in header(.h) files. But at linking time the (global) variables in implementation(.m) files are also checked and if there any duplicate, Linker will through error :  duplicate symbol _xyz

Comment: I had to rename even local variables                                                  
    @implementation DIOOutstreamVideoView
CGFloat visibleHeightOut;
CGFloat fullHeightOut;

Answer (score 36):

I have same problem.
In Xcode 7.2 in path Project Target > Build Setting > No Common Blocks, i change it to NO.

Answer (score 34):

I found the accepted answer touches on the problem but didn't help me solve it, hopefully this answer will help with this very frustrating issue.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BLoginViewController._hud in:

17 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

*"Means that you have loaded same functions twice. As the issue disappear after removing  -ObjC from Other Linker Flags, this means that this option result that functions loads twice:"*

In layman's terms this means we have two files in our project with exactly the same name. Maybe you are combining one project into another one? Have a look at the errors above the "duplicate symbols" error to see which folder is duplicated, in my case it was BLoginViewController.

For example, in the image below you can see I have two BImageViewControllers, for me this is what was causing the issue.

As soon as I deleted one then the issue vanished :)

[image]

Comment: Huge help, thank you. I have taken a backup of a project that uses cocoapods. In forgetting I needed to open the workspace when I reloaded the backup in Xcode and found it wouldn't build, I then added AFNetworking directly to the project.  I subsequently went on to re-setup my cocoapods, which included AFNetworking as a dependency and forgot to remove the original AFNetworking folder that I had added to my project.

Answer (score 33):

This occurred on me when I accepted "recommended settings" pop-up on a project that I develop two years ago in Objective-C.

The problem was that when you accepted the "recommended settings" update, Xcode automatically changed or added some build settings, including `GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES;`.

This made the build failed with the `duplicate symbol` error in my updated project. So I changed `No Common Block` to `NO` in my build settings and the error was gone.

Comment: Yeah, this helped me. Xcode 8, updated an older project to recommended settings. Switched this back and I'm good to go again. Thanks!

Comment: Good job. Helped me a lot! An up vote for you darling! ;-)

Comment: Brilliant mate :)

Answer (score 24):

I experienced this issue after installing Cocoapods. Now happens everytime I update some pods. Solution I've found:

Go to terminal:

```
1) pod deintegrate
2) pod install
```

Also, check the item "Always Embed Swift Libraries" in your Build Settings. It should be "faded" indicating it is using the default configuration. If its set to a manual YES, hit delete over it to revert it to the default configuration. This stopped the behavior.

Comment: This worked for me. However, "Always Embed Swift Libraries" was already set to NO. I switched it to YES and then hit delete and then ran the pod functions stated above.

Answer (score 20):

Fastest way to find the duplicate is:

1. Go to Targets
2. Go to Build Phases
3. Go to Compile Sources
4. Delete duplicate files.

Comment: Add a couple more hours to that.

Comment: which is only for class files like .h, .m or .swift files. Not for frame work level files.

Comment: This was the easiest way. Thanks! I was having that problem with a c code and I follow this steps and it work. Although I have to clarify that don't delete the file with your main function because it won't work.

Comment: Thanks! man. Atlast for your answer I'm able to run the app for first time... Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 18):

- Go to Targets
- Select Build Settings
- Search for ***"No Common Blocks"***, select it to **NO**.

It worked for me

Comment: Didn't worked for me

Answer (score 15):

Following steps solved the issue for me.

1. Go to Build Phases in Target settings.
2. Go to “Link Binary With Libraries”.
3. Check if any of the libraries exist twice.
4. Build again.

Answer (score 13):

Remove -ObjC from Other Linker Flags or
Please check you imported any .m file instead of .h by mistake.

Comment: Hey, everybody, who is still wondering why -ObjC flag doesn't work - pay attention to this answer. I was completely wrong thinking -ObjC flag doesn't work in my "super special" case. After searching through the project for smth like `.m"` I have noticed that I did import .m file instead of .h and after fixing that it just worked!
`Talk is cheap, show me the code!` Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

Update answer for 2021, Xcode 12.X:

```
pod deintegrate 
pod install
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

My situation with some legacy project opened in Xcode 7.3 was:

```
duplicate symbol _SomeEnumState in:
```

followed with list of two unrelated files.o, then this was repeated couple of times, then finally:

```
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What solved it for me was changing enum declaration from:

```
enum SomeEnumState {
    SomeEnumStateActive = 0,
    SomeEnumStateUsed = 1,
    SomeEnumStateHidden = 2
} SomeEnumState;
```

to this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SomeEnumState) {
    SomeEnumStateActive = 0,
    SomeEnumStateUsed = 1,
    SomeEnumStateHidden = 2
};
```

If somebody has explanation for this, please enlighten me.

Comment: Same thing fixed it for me, when I switched enum to typedef NS_ENUM it fixed the duplicate symbols error

Answer (score 9):

Defining same variable under @implementation in more than one class also can cause this problem.

Comment: but why? same happened to me with plain C functions with same names

Answer (score 9):

In my case, there were two file by same name in the location

> Targets > Build Phases > Compile Sources and delete any duplicate files.

Answer (score 9):

My problem was that I had 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64. After reading this post and their answers, I try with the common solution about change `GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES` to `NO`

But, instead of working for me, I went from 5 duplicates to 1 duplicate...

So, I paid attention to that last error, and I realized what was my problem, and it was an "incompatibility" with these packages (I had both in `package.json`):

```
rn-fetch-blob
react-native-blob-util
```

The message was clear about it, and I remove `rn-fetch-blob` because I have not idea why it was in my project, but, I only used with jest and delete it, it wasn't a problem.

So, after removing that package, and run `yarn` again, problem solved... And without changing the `GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS`

Comment: Thank you, it didn't solve my problem but decreased the duplications from 14 to 9

Comment: the rest solved by removing "use_flipper!()" from podFile

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!! And thanks for your input!

Comment: rn-fetch-blob is deprecated at this point and react-native-blob-util is a fork from it. If you use both you get this issue. I had the same problem. In the end, I had to manually link the library for some other compatibility problem but the issue was gone.

Answer (score 7):

For me during the Xcode8 recommended project settings update "No Common Blocks" to YES which causes this issue.

Comment: Same here for Xcode8.2.1, when applied to an old project.

Comment: This fixed it on XCode 11.3.1 too

Comment: Where can I have this option?

Answer (score 5):

Today , I got the same error . The error's key word is `duplicate`. I fix it by:

```
1. Remove the duplicate file at Build Phases-->Compile Sources
2. If you can not remove it at Build Phases, you need find the file at your project and remove the reference by DELETE :
```

[image: remove reference]

```
3. Add the file to your project again
4. Add the file's .m to your Build Phases-->Compile Sources again
5. Build your project, the error will disappear
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I compiled two main.m where one was the old reference. This was caused by drag and drop.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error when I added a pod repository

```
pod 'SWRevealViewController'
```

for an already added source code (SWRevealViewController) from gitHub. So, the error will be fixed by either removing the source code or pod repository.

**Case # 2:**

The 2nd time, this error appeared when I declare a **constant in .h** file.

```
NSString * const SomeConstant  = @"SomeValue";
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
...
...
```

Comment: Case 2nd saved me a night. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another silly mistake that will cause this error is repeated files. I accidentally copied some files twice. First I went to Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile sources. There I noticed some files on that list twice and their locations.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you haven't imported a .m file by accident, you might want to delete your derived data in the Projects Window and then build and run again.

Answer (score 4):

None of above solutions works for me, I just fixed it myself.

I got duplicate symbol of my `core data model` which I make it myself, but 
in my `.xcdatamodeld` inspector, I choose `Class Definition` of `Codegen` property, I guess that's what's wrong with. Then I choose `Manual/None`,it got fixed.

Hope this can be helpful for you!

Comment: This will help anyone who adds tables periodically to their .xcdatamodel, I'm bookmarking this response since I do this only often enough to completely forget how to fix the problem when it happens again.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who is having this issue, I didn't see my resolution in any of these answers.

After having a .pbxproj merge conflict which was manually addressed (albeit poorly), there were duplicate references to individual class files in the .pbxproj. Deleting those from the Project > Build Phases > Compile Sources fixed everything for me.

Hope this helps someone down the line.

Comment: also had merging conflicts and had to manually resolve them in pbxproj file. Ended up with `ld: X duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`. Fixed it by removing the source files mentioned in error message and re-adding them again to the project.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Juice007, I had declared and initialized a C type variable in two different .m files (that weren't imported!)

```
BOOL myVar = NO;
```

however, this method of declaring and initializing a variable, even in .m, even in @implementation grants it global scope. Your options are:

1. Declare it as static, to limit the scope to class:

   ```
   static BOOL myVar = NO;
   ```
2. Remove the initialization (which will make the two classes share the global var):

   ```
   BOOL myVar;
   -(void) init{
       myVar = NO;
   }
   ```
3. Declare it as a property:

   ```
   @property BOOL myVar;
   ```
4. Declare it as a proper iVar in the @interface

   ```
   @interface myClass(){
       BOOL myVar;
   }
   @end
   ```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had two `main()` methods defined in my project and removing one solved the issue.

Comment: Had the same problem here. Your post helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The answers above didn't work for me. Here's how I got around it:

1) in finder, delete the entire Pods folder and Podfile.lock file 
2) close the xcode project 
3) run pod install in the terminal
4) open the xcode project, run the clean build command

Worked for me after that.

Answer (score 4):

Because I haven't seen this answer:

Uninstall and reinstall your podfiles! [Remove or uninstall library previously added : cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods)

I've run into this issue over 3 times building my app and every time this is what fixes it. :)

Comment: I've also been running into this a lot more lately. Not sure if it has something to do with Xcode 11 or Catalina but this is what usually fixes my project as well.

1. Open your Podfile
2. Comment out `ALL` your pods
3. Run `pod install`
4. Uncomment your pods in the Podfile
5. Run `pod install` again
6. Profit

Comment: @kiloLoco Yeah I think it's a bug in Xcode? Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I've just had this error as well. Found that the problem was variables declared with global scope, with the same names, were being repeated throughout the files being compiled into the program. Once changing the global variables to local scope to the pseudo-main function the error was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

If you're coming here for a `React Native` Project, then go to the following,

```
Targets -> <Your-App> -> Build Settings -> Dead Code Stripping
```

Change from `No` to `Yes` for `Debug`.

P.S. This approach works for React Native projects, not sure if it will work for a native project too.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue happen with me, when I was integrating the lob project inside my project.

[image]

Actually lob project also have the AFNetworking files,
So I remove the .m files from lob project.

[image]

Actually .m files are conflicting with My project POd/AFNetworking/ .m files

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Recently had a headache looking for source of an error. I was wondered, when i found out that my app doesn't want to compile, simply because i had following code snippet in different classes:

```
dispatch_time_t getDispatchTimeByDate(NSDate *date)
{
    NSTimeInterval interval;
    double second, subsecond;
    struct timespec time;
    dispatch_time_t milestone;


    interval = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
    subsecond = modf(interval, &second);
    time.tv_sec = second;
    time.tv_nsec = subsecond * NSEC_PER_SEC;
    milestone = dispatch_walltime(&time, 0);

    return milestone;
}
```

Hope that might help someone.

Comment: small helper function, accidentally copied, easily overlooked - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I hope it will definitely help you

I got same error **3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64**

in my case I have copied code from another file of same project eg. code of A.m file to B.m and after complilation i got an error as mention. and i have solve error by changing the name of global Variable.

this error came in my case because of same declare for global variable in both file.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, this happens when you have the wrong file in import like for ex.:

> import "MenuItem.m"

Instead of

> import "MenuItem.h"

this will throw that duplicate error *duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64*

Answer (score 3):

For me, this happened when mistakenly I defined two entry points for my APP

@main
struct AppName: App {
//Comment - @main

Or

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate
//Comment - @UIApplicationMain

Comment: That was it for me. I copied and pasted one app into another, and forgot the pasted SwiftUI app had its own @main entry.  Therefore 2 entry points to my app.

Comment: This is what helped me! I was adding SwiftUI to my existing project and adding @main to my SwiftUI class.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 6.3.2. I have checked all possibility like as belowed

1: I have not import .m file in my project.

2: Removed `-ObjC` from **Other linker flag**.

3: Removed all my **derive Data**.

still i am getting same error. **I have removed this error by removing any variable declaration from `.pch` file**. in my case, i have declared `AppDelegate` object in `.pch` file. finally i found reason that cause error. so i remove declaration of any variable from .pch file and my project working charm.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this fault today.That's because I defined a const value in a `.m` file.But I defined another `.m` file that also included this const value.That's means it has two same const values.So this error appears.
And my solution is adding a keyword "`static`" before the const value.such as:

```
static CGFloat const btnConunt = 9;
```

And then I build the project it won't report this error.

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to Build Phases

2.Search for the file name

3.Delete duplicate

-> Error will go away.

If it doesn't, try to search for "file.m", if you see any #import "file.m" , clear this line

Answer (score 2):

I face the same error what i did

**1.Copy the duplicate symbol file (class name or framework name) from the end which is just showed above of the line (duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64).**

**2. Paste it in Find Navigator and press enter**

It showed me duplicate class. I remove the duplicate class and run successfully.

Answer (score 2):

This error generally occurs when you have linked any library or file twice. In the error desciption, the name of the duplicated file will be listed, you can search and and make sure you don't have duplicates. If you find duplicates, remove reference to one of them to play safe

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you are not importing [ViewController.m] instead of header file

```
#import "ViewController.m"
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer explains well as to why this problem occurs:

[Xcode C++ :: Duplicate Symbols for Architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436981/xcode-c-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

In my opinion you do not need to turn any of the flags off or change Xcode settings, re-read your code, and fix the problem. Changing the settings would just subside the inflammation not the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Remove -all_load from Other Linker Flags. It works on my project

Comment: This got rid of the error for me but now got `determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, lookupAdConversionDetails:, transform:`, maybe unrelated

Answer (score 2):

If you're using and think it might be your pods, try this:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encoutered the problem. The `pod deintegrate` or `Removing podfile.lock` ways would be helpful for you, but try the following sequence , that may be more helpful than deintegrating the pod files

- Comment all the pods in `Podfile`
- run the `pod install`, it will remove `Pods` folder from the project
- Uncomment all the pods in `Podfile`
- run again `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

If you have some common functions defined in a header file, change them into `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was having implemented functions in header files.
There should be a clear separation between function definitions in header files, and function implementations in the code files.

For example, I had something like:

`my_header.h`

```
#ifdef my_header_h
#define my_header_h

int foo() { return 123; }

#endif // my_header_h
```

which should be:

```
#ifdef my_header_h
#define my_header_h

int foo();

#endif // my_header_h
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried following this steps and It works for me now.

1. Open Xcode > Pods > Targets Support Files > Pods-{TARGET-NAME}

   find "OTHER_LDFLAGS" and remove only "-ObjC" in these two files:

   Pods-{TARGET-NAME}.release.xcconfig & Pods-{TARGET-NAME}.debug.xcconfig
2. Go to project main target > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags:

   Make sure no "-ObjC" is left in the value
3. I deleted the build/Build folder in ios and run-ios again. It works now.

Comment: I tried every solution on here and after 2 days, this was the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

**This Answer works with Xcode 12.5.1, worked for me on 2021**

1. Close your Xcode project.
2. Go to your project directory, if you use flutter don't forget to get in "ios" file in the project folder.
3. Delete [Pods, Podfile, Podfile.lock].
4. Run the terminal.
5. Go to your project directory.

**If you use swift you're done here jump to xcode and run the app or keep on if you're using flutter**

6. Run `flutter clean`.
7. Run `flutter pub get`.
8. Run `flutter run`. *Don't forget to run the simulator before you use flutter run command*.

Congrats everything should work!

Answer (score 1):

For the case of **React Native**, the solution was simply deleting all of the libraries in: Target > Build Phases > Link Binary with Library.

[image: Link Binary with Library]

I don't really know the cause, but I assume React Native already has the packages installed, creating duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

When using swiftui swift package manager, remove **@Main** attribute from swiftui code.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when I implemented a class method with a scope resolution operator in the **header** file, instead of **.cpp** file.

PS: And I was programming in C++ on Macbook Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I named an Entity of my Core Data Model the same as an Object.
So: I defined an object "Event.h" and at the same time I had this entity called "Event". I ended up renaming the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try clear all plugin under the plugin folder?

It is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the pod and Libraries you added. There should be one or more libraries are repeated. Please remove it from one side. I will fix the issue. And the effected library will listed in x-code error message detail.

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall the pod which it is related to and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above mentioned answer helped, as i had similar errors in pods and locally stored framework that looked like this,

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_EZAudioDevice' in:
    /Users/(yourUserName)/Desktop/Source Code/(yourProjectName)/Pods/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit.framework/AudioKit(EZAudioDevice.o)
    /Users/(yourUserName)/Desktop/Source Code/(yourProjectName)/ChirpSDK.framework/ChirpSDK(EZAudioDevice.o)
```

So the fix was to locate `/Users/(yourUserName)/Desktop/Source Code/(yourProjectName)/Pods` directory in project where you will find these two files namely,

- Pods-(yourProjectName).debug.xcconfig
- Pods-(yourProjectName).release.xcconfig

In both of these files, you need to remove `-ObjC` flag under `OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited)`, the rational for removing this is as same as already mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24300502/5484311)

Answer (score 0):

I simply just unistalled all my pods and reinstalled them. I also got rid of some pods i did not use.

Answer (score 0):

**Open your project in XCode**

you will see the sidebar now focus on the attached image.[image]

Search your specific SDK or any dublicate file where you facing an issue.

You will see that you have added any file **twice**.

**just remove that file and your issue will be resolved.**

**Note:** you have to remove the file from that place where you add it wrongly.

**FOR EXAMPLE**
[image]

**Note:** Just remove FBSDKCoreKit from **Frameworks**

***Good Luck***

Answer (score 0):

I`ve got this error after installed alamofire`s pod, but alamafire was already installed as package through xcode`s File/Add Packages.... error gone after I removed the package and also removed it from Targets/General/Frameworks...

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced this issue on FBReactNativeSpec, just made check on Run script - For install builds only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in Xcode 14. Cleaning the build folder worked for me.

Select "Clean Build Folder" option from "Product" menu.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have solved this by deleting pods which is related to Fabric, because it was conflicting with Crashlitics pod, since they actually duplicate each other, because Fabric it's just old version of Crashlitics

Answer (score 0):

My issue with this error was the Podfile.
I'm using Firebase and one of their pods was the problem.

1. I removed all firebase pods from the Podfile
2. Deleted the derived data by running this code in the terminal.
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
3. then reinstalled the pods I needed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still unable to resolve this issue, try Product > Clean Build Folder ...

That's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i changed the Build System to Legacy and it worked.

You can access this option in the menu:

**File > Workspace Settings > Build System**

[image]

Comment: Legacy Build System Deprecated