# Xcode C++ :: Duplicate Symbols for Architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, clang

I am new to Xcode and when I build the following code (an MWE), I get the following error

> ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have three files as following;

> main.cpp

```
#include "B.cpp"
int main() {
  square(5);
  return 0;
}
```

> B.cpp

```
#include "A.cpp"

void square(int n){
  display(n*n);
}
```

> A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(int num){
  cout<<num;
}
```

I have tried different methods mentioned on stack overflow like change "Build Active Architecture Only" to "Yes" and some others but the error still persists.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Problem is that `main.cpp` has included `B.cpp` and `A.cpp`. In your build process, you are also compiling `B.cpp` and `A.cpp` and trying to link `B.o` and `A.o` alongwith `main.o`.

Linking `B.o` and `A.o` causes symbols `display` and `square` to be defined multiple times. `display` is defined 3 times and `square` defined 2 times.

You just compile and build `main.cpp`. Do not build `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`.

**Second** way is that make `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` to `A.h` and `B.h` and functions `inline`. So, they will be compiled only once.

**Third** way, do not include `B.cpp` in `main.cpp`. Just put function declaration instead of inclusion.

```
//main.cpp

void square(int);

int main() {
  square(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Generally, function declarations are put in header files. If that is required in multiple cases, make a header file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried in the following manner but the error still persists. 

1. Clean the Project. 
2. Select "Main.cpp" 
3. Product -> Perform Action -> Compile "Main.cpp" 
4. Repeated Step 3, for "A.cpp" and "B.cpp"
5. Run the Project.  
6. Got the same error. 

I also tried to compile only "Main.cpp" and then run but XCode build the complete project.<br/>

Can you please elaborate how to compile and build "Main.cpp" independently.


P.S. I am using XCode 6.1.1

Comment: @Ahmad you're still not getting it. You're including the same source in **two different translation units**. The code in `A.cpp` is compiled as a single translation unit to `A.o`, then the *same code* is `#include`-ed into `main.cpp` (which is the **real** problem). The second option in this answer is ideal. Do that.

Comment: @WhozCraig
Thank you.

I used the second option, which solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I used the first solution, this solved my problem

Comment: Nicely explained! Thanks a lot. I have been suffering by this issue for past 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

For me, changing '**No Common Blocks**' from Yes to No ( under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation ) fixed the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jux1d.png)