# ld: 87 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, parse-platform

There are many issues regarding this problem in here. But still could not find the solution. I apologize if I am missing stupid thing because I am very new in cordova. I followed this [link](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/native/existing) to add notifications on iOS app using parse and cordova. Then I encountered this problem;

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._URL in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appStoreId in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkTarget._appName in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkTarget in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkTarget in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkTarget.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkTarget.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFTaskCompletionSource._task in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource in: BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFTaskCompletionSource.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._includeStatusBarInSize in:BoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o) /Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
ld: 87 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Sorry could not post image as I do not have 10 reputation. And did not paste all the errors.

Then I thought that the plugins has been duplicated from the downloads folder(`parse-library-1.7.5`). So I deleted the folder. Then I cleaned, prepared and run the project again. Then, again I encountered another error;

```
Ld /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoatDay-bshyzslutlotwzemexzolhojdvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoatDay.app/BoatDay normal x86_64
cd /Users/Daniel/GitHub/boat-day-app/platforms/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoatDay-bshyzslutlotwzemexzolhojdvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoatDay-bshyzslutlotwzemexzolhojdvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -FBoatDay/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect -F/Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5 -filelist /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoatDay-bshyzslutlotwzemexzolhojdvne/Build/Intermediates/BoatDay.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoatDay.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BoatDay.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -lsqlite3 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -weak_framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -weak_framework AudioToolbox -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoatDay-bshyzslutlotwzemexzolhojdvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a -framework MobileCoreServices -framework FacebookSDK -weak_framework Social -framework Bolts -weak_framework Accounts -framework Parse -weak_framework ImageIO -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoatDay-bshyzslutlotwzemexzolhojdvne/Build/Intermediates/BoatDay.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoatDay.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BoatDay_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Daniel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoatDay-bshyzslutlotwzemexzolhojdvne/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoatDay.app/BoatDay 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Daniel/Downloads/parse-library-1.7.5'
 ld: framework not found Bolts 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What could be problem in my case? Any kind of hints or solutions would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check you have import .m file somewhere

Comment: have you declared any variable in .pch file?

Comment: i have recently faced same problem, kindly checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64/31473695#31473695

Comment: @aBilal17 Yeah there are .m file imported.

Comment: @None I have not declared any variable in .pch file

Comment: change that .m to .h

Comment: In My case I had to use `extern` in front of every `NSString *const` declaration and it solved the problem.