# How to fix this duplicate symbol error, xcode 7.0.1

Tags: xcode, google-analytics

I searched and searched and couldnt find the answer.

I added google analytics to my project.
I have two projects in the same workspace that use google analytics.
I linked them both. In the past this wasnt an issue.
But then I needed to add another library, so i ran "pod update"
and since then i've been getting this error.
Now, both locations are EXACTLY the same file.

How can I fix this error?
(as a sub note, no .m files were imported, and there are no duplicate library entries in the pbxproj file regarding this thing)

```
duplicate symbol _UselessFunctionThatExistsSolelySoThatIDontGetErrorsAboutEmptyLibsF474397331760491295374 in:
    /Users/Lena/Dev/workspace/app/myapp/../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a(StaticLibraryEmptySourceFile.o)
    /Users/Lena/Dev/workspace/app/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a(StaticLibraryEmptySourceFile.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Is another library is also from google? one from these Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, Maps ?

Comment: only Analytics ; this part of the comment is not needed for nothing other than making the comment long enough, the first part is completely sufficient to answer the question

Comment: [Follow this link. Hope your problem gets resolved ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate symbols for architecture x86\_64 under Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode)