# Updating pods results to a linker error

Tags: xcode, swift, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I have a problem updating my pods. I am working on a project built by someone else, and there are pods installed. I found out there are new versions of the pods and decided to update them all. It goes perfect `

```
pod update result is:

Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing GGLInstanceID 1.2.1 (was 1.1.4)
Installing Google 2.0.4 (was 1.3.2)
Installing GoogleCloudMessaging 1.2.0 (was 1.1.2)
Installing GoogleIPhoneUtilities 1.2.0 (was 1.1.0)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities 1.2.0 (was 1.1.0)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities 1.2.0 (was 1.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities 1.1.0 (was 1.0.3)
Installing GoogleUtilities 1.3.0 (was 1.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 8 total pods installed.`
```

All good, but when I launch my workspace i recieve a nasty linker error which ends in ..:

```
   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GSDK_GTMReadMonitorInputStream._inputStream in:
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full_external.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GSDK_GTMReadMonitorInputStream._readDelegate in:
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full_external.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GSDK_GTMReadMonitorInputStream._readSelector in:
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full_external.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GSDK_GTMReadMonitorInputStream._runLoopModes in:
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full_external.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GSDK_GTMReadMonitorInputStream._thread in:
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full_external.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GSDK_GTMReadMonitorInputStream in:
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full_external.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
    /Users/macbookair/Documents/Fuelo/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
ld: 289 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What should it be ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: hey this problem seems to have been addressed in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64). It might help.

Comment: I did read everything in that thread before, sadly nothing cleans the error.