# Xcode 7 simulator error "duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

My development environment with `Xcode 7.2.1`, `CocoaPods 1.0.0` and `GoogleMaps 1.13.2`

I can build code successful to generate a XXX.ipa file and install in my iPhone 6 Plus to work correctly.

But when I run Xcode simulator by item "iPhone 6" or "iPhone 6 Plus" always get the information as below

> "xxxx duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64" "linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I use the following solutions still can't fix it

1. Build Options -> Enable Bitcode -> set "No"
2. Remove -ObjC from Other Linker Flags
3. project Targer -> Build phases -> compile sources, ckeck no duplicate files
4. Make sure I haven't #imported a .m file

I am wondering if there are any other method to solve this, help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Stupid one, but make sure you haven't #imported a .m file by mistake somewhere

Comment: You can check this one as well. Changing 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No ( under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation ) fixed the problem.

Comment: You can check the meaning and how to solve your error here in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64?rq=1)

Comment: @aBilal17 your answer is a copy of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25666570/6124910

Comment: @Patrick its not an answer its a comment.

Comment: @Ethan Sometime we delete the files from project and the files are still in the directory of the project . So please check your directory if you have duplicate files or not . Nada Gamal

Answer (score 2):

This error generally occurs when you have linked any library or file twice.
In the error desciption, the name of the duplicated file will be listed, you can search and and make sure you don't have duplicates.
If you find duplicates, remove reference to one of them to play safe

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar kind of issue.

In my application I have run my code and created ipa before two day. And today when I am trying to run same code without any changes I am getting:

> ld: 102 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The solution for this duplication Linker error can be solved by Remove all of your **classes** from **compile sources**, then click the **+ button** and search for the term `'.m'`. Highlight every class, then **click add**. Build and run again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be occurred in case you import ".m" file instead of ".h" by mistake. I know it may be seemed as a stupid advise but this is what I had done in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by removing the `-all_load` flag in the **`Build Settings-> Other Linker flags`**.