# ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I didn't add -ObjC to other linker flags.  This seems to be the two question. Now , I wonder why it's running in my iPhone, but Xcode7.3 can't do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [duplicate symbols for architecture x86\_64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: I didn't add -ObjC to other linker flags. This seems to be the two question. Now , I wonder why it's running in my iPhone, but Xcode7.3 can't do it.