# Appodeal SDK "duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I have implement Appodeal framework, but after that i cant build my project because it gives following error.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MoPub._globalMediationSettings in:
/Users/ci-13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-ewtecqfvsvbwpmbxhdskxxrchrda/Build/Intermediates/myproject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MoPub.o
/Volumes/Projects/myproject/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(MoPub.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MoPub in:
/Users/ci-13/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-ewtecqfvsvbwpmbxhdskxxrchrda/Build/Intermediates/myproject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MoPub.o
/Volumes/Projects/myproject/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(MoPub.o)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64