# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 error when building IOS application in ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic2

I built an ionic app and built the IOS app from it. I used firebase push notifications in this applications when I tried to build the IOS application keeps getting this error. How can I get rid of the duplicate files mentioned in here

duplicate symbol _GTMNSDataZlibRemainingBytesKey in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMNSData+zlib_b66d12cf522b1bac6527d4b701a2e6f4.o)
    duplicate symbol _GTMNSDataZlibErrorKey in:

```
    /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMNSData+zlib_b66d12cf522b1bac6527d4b701a2e6f4.o)
    duplicate symbol _GTMNSDataZlibErrorDomain in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMNSData+zlib_b66d12cf522b1bac6527d4b701a2e6f4.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogMaximumLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogMaximumLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogAllowedLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogAllowedLevelFilter in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogger in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogLevelFilter.userDefaults_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogAllowedLevelFilter.allowedLevels_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogger.formatter_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter.dateFormatter_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogger.filter_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogger.writer_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter.pname_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter.pid_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMLogLevelFilter.verboseLoggingEnabled_ in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_1d87861920ce748f18c427633f13fd22.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GPBFloatArray._capacity in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf/libProtobuf.a(GPBArray.o)
        Sale Ching/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf(GPBArray_9c18dd0099bac64399d692ec28726322.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GPBEnumArray._capacity in:
        /Users/uvinduchandrasiri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sale_Ching-fmystclqwodflqflbkuaoyjyhfbc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf/libProtobuf.a(GPBArray.o)
duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Check whether you have added files or framework twice. Or try to clear the derived data and check it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

This means that you have loaded same functions twice. As the issue disappears after removing  -ObjC from Other Linker Flags, this means that this option result that functions loads twice:

from Technical Q&A

> This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library
>   that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will
>   typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code
>   loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of
>   effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on
>   existing classes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode) for further details

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same problem.Somehow some frameworks got added twice in our project.So I fixed it by removing the duplicate frameworks from project settings -> build phases -> link Binary with libraries then check some frameworks may be added multiple times, just find the repeated frameworks and remove them, then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when multiple libraries (object files) are sharing the same variable/function name, generating duplicate symbols. The compiler gets confused about which one should be invoked.

To solve the issue, we can either make functions **inline** or use **macros** instead of the function name. We can also make function scope local to the library only by using **static**.