# React Native Facebook SDK: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm building a React Native app. To use Facebook Login I added the Facebook SDK to my app. During development on iOS and both during development and production on Android everything worked perfectly fine.

But when I followed [this guide from the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#building-your-app-for-production) to build the release build of my app for production, I see the following error:

```
// ... more of the 'duplicate' messages
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKAppInviteContent._appLinkURL in:
    /Users/<me>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<appname>-cbmpafcjctjlojapgnzaxdbmmopf/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit/libFBSDKShareKit.a(FBSDKAppInviteContent.o)
    /Users/<me>/Startup/react-native/<appname>/ios/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKAppInviteContent.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBSDKAppInviteContent._appInvitePreviewImageURL in:
    /Users/<me>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<appname>-cbmpafcjctjlojapgnzaxdbmmopf/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit/libFBSDKShareKit.a(FBSDKAppInviteContent.o)
    /Users/<me>/Startup/react-native/<appname>/ios/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit(FBSDKAppInviteContent.o)
ld: 1164 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I googled this error but couldn't find anything about this. What is going wrong? Why does this error only occur when building for production?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate symbols for architecture x86\_64 under Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode)