# How to fix this error: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 in C with Xcode?

Tags: c

I am new to Xcode, and have created a simple program in C as shown below.

I keep getting the error 
"1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64";

I haven't included any other files than the ones I have shown below

```
int changer(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int one, two;
    int s;
    scanf("%d %d", &one, &two);
    s=changer(one, two);
    printf("%d %d %d \n", one, two, s);


}
int changer (int a, int b)
{
    ++a;
    ++b;
    return a+b;

}
```

I want to investigate how passing arguments to user-defined functions works in C.

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: Never used XCode, but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode can be useful to you.

Comment: @tkausl, There is no other error message. It just says "Build Failed" and then 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64".

Comment: You are missing `#include <stdio.h>`