# how to solve the duplicate symbols for architecture

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I built a mobile application with flutter framework and every time I run the application on ios devise this error appears and

```
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file
    'Runner/Info.plist'.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    duplicate symbol _kFIRInstanceIDDomain in:
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceI
        D/libFirebaseInstanceID.a(NSError+FIRInstanceID 2.o)
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceI
        D/libFirebaseInstanceID.a(NSError+FIRInstanceID.o)
    duplicate symbol _kFIRMessagingDomain in:
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseMessaging
        /libFirebaseMessaging.a(NSError+FIRMessaging 2.o)
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseMessaging
        /libFirebaseMessaging.a(NSError+FIRMessaging.o)
    duplicate symbol _GULNSDataZlibRemainingBytesKey in:
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/l
        ibGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 2.o)
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/l
        ibGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
    duplicate symbol _GULNSDataZlibErrorKey in:
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/l
        ibGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 2.o)
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/l
        ibGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
    duplicate symbol _GULNSDataZlibErrorDomain in:
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/l
        ibGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib 2.o)
        /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Desktop/amafe/AMAFE/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities/l
        ibGoogleUtilities.a(GULNSData+zlib.o)
    ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone XR.
```

I don't have a background coding with Xcode how can I solve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate symbols for architecture x86\_64 under Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode)

Comment: I did everything but still have the same errors!!