# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 under gcc-10

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-errors, lapack

I'm attempting to install an open source software qml in Mac high sierra. It's an interface btw kdb+ and LAPACK,BLAS. I've got the error message:

```
gcc-10 -m64  -fPIC -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o qml.so const.o alloc.o util.o opt.o libm.o cephes.o lapack.o conmin.o conmax.o nlopt.o \
        ../lib/libprob.a ../lib/libconmax.a ../lib/libnlopt.a \
         \
        -llapack -lblas \
        -lgfortran \
        -lm \
        -exported_symbols_list qml.symlist
duplicate symbol _call in:
    conmin.o
    conmax.o
duplicate symbol _call in:
    conmin.o
    nlopt.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I did some research and saw people fixed this issue by removing some Flags. [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode) can anyone help to see if any FLAG should be removed? Thanks. Here are the Flags:
FLAGS          :=  -m64  -fPIC -pipe
LD_SHARED      := -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup

Comment: If it worked with gcc 9 and earlier, then I think you need to add `-fcommon`. In gcc 10 the default was changed to `-fno-common`, see [gcc changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html#c).

Comment: thanks a lot, it works.