# 44 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

When I ran my project on Xcode After installing some pods in my project I was getting the following error:-

```
44 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Can anyone please let me know how can I resolve this issue? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate symbols for architecture x86\_64 under Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode)

Comment: @Martheen I followed the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108247/13218692

Comment: @Martheen But, it didn't worked for me :( Any other solution?

Comment: Other answers in that question target the pods, have you tried them?

Comment: @Martheen No, not yet

Comment: @Martheen I was able to resolve the issue by deleting all the duplicated file manually. Thanks for the help!!