# Error of 48 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I had error:48 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64:[image]
when I followed the tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#analytics-enabled, after install required libraries in cocoapods, it started to pop me this error message:[image]
Then I followed my discussion to remove `-ObjeC` in `other linker flags` in this StackOverflow discussion: [Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 under Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode), but I did it in my project IFTTT rather than pods, should I do remove -ObjeC in other in Pods or my project? I did it on my project page, and after removing it, it still displays `-ObjeC` on the setting page, and I still got the same error message:[image]
does anyone know why? Yea I was totally in a mess, can someone please help me with this? thank you!

Update:
I came out the solution in my case, I had cocoapods and some libraries installed before, I am trying to set up firebase, so if you encounter these problems when installing firebase, definitely reference this post. I followed the answer below, and before that, I added:

```
  post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = "NO"
  end
end
end
```

and then did following command:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod cache clean --all
$ pod install
```

as answer shows, then everything worked out, I did delete some duplicate files when there was file.c and file 2.c, but I didn't delete all to try, I just did what I had above and fix this problem, hope this will help future developers, don't freak out! trust yourself and other people from StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes that happens with me when I try to update pods. What happens is a duplicate of some files in pods gets added in. It will look something like this:

```
Firebase.h
Firebase 2.h
```

You could just go through all the pods you installed and delete the duplicates, or you can deintegrate and install again.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod cache clean --all
$ pod install
```

Comment: I follow your step and I still have the error, but it moves from Mantle to nanopb: 35 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64, but I did find that the file has pb.h and also pb 2.h, should I delete one of them?

Comment: yes, delete all duplicates that have "2" in them.