# (FirebaseFireStoreSwift Pod) ld: 201 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am trying to add the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` pod to my project so I can encode and decode custom objects with FireStore. My project was running but I added it to my podfile and get some duplicate errors when building. (Build succeeds when I remove it from my Podfile.

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalyticsConfiguration' in:
/Users/~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/community-garden-ios-duyohzbycrzylgdmgnstqtwukjjf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore.o
/Users/~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/community-garden-ios-duyohzbycrzylgdmgnstqtwukjjf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.o)
```

You can view complete error [here](https://gist.github.com/Pape98/02d89c6aeb025151b11aa2599c972882)

I am a newbie to iOS and I have spent days researching the problem but most Stackoverflow posts deal with people writing objective C-code. I've tried to look compiled sources but no files were linked twice.

This image shows the targets of my Pods

[image]

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Did it resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

By referring to a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137216/error-of-48-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64/65137598) which is also mentioning the duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 error, it is due to a **duplicate of some files in pods that is getting added in**. The solution is to **delete the duplicate files inside the pod**, or **de-integrate and install them again**.
You may also refer to the similar [GitHub issue](https://coderedirect.com/questions/350720/firebase-pods-generate-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64).