# OpenGL on Mac Xcode

Tags: c++, glut

I'm trying to run this code on Xcode but I get build failed although I'm sure that my code is right

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include "labThree.hpp"


void myInit(void){
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,1000.0,0.0,600.0);
    
}

void myDisplay(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex2i(50,500);
    glVertex2i(100,550);
    glVertex2i(50,600);
    glEnd();
    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex2i(200,500);
    glVertex2i(200,600);
    glVertex2i(150,550);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
    glLineWidth(5.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0);
    glVertex2i(100,200);
    glVertex2i(50,50);
    glVertex2i(100,100);
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex2i(150,150);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex2i(200,200);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex2i(250,200);
    glVertex2i(350,200);
    glVertex2i(400,325);
    glVertex2i(300,325);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex2i(775,425);
    glVertex2i(825,475);
    glVertex2i(775,475);
    glVertex2i(825,500);
    glVertex2i(750,500);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex2i(500,600);
    glVertex2i(500,400);
    glVertex2i(600,550);
    glVertex2i(600,350);
    glVertex2i(700,500);
    glVertex2i(700,300);
    glEnd();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex2i(500,200);
    glVertex2i(500,150);
    glVertex2i(550,100);
    glVertex2i(600,150);
    glVertex2i(600,200);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    
    

}

int main(int argc ,char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE||GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000,600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Display Graphic Primitives");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
    
    
}
```

please help i have an assignment due tomorrow and this is not working
I did the Glew setup for Mac
and I did a simple window app and it was working fine but this one is not working
is there any specific thing that I have to do because I'm using Mac?

Comment: `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE||GLUT_RGB);` Why logical OR is used here?

Comment: What error do you get? What is `"labThree.hpp"`?

Comment: sorry its supposed to be | instead of || but also that's not the problem

Comment: @MikeCAT labThree.hpp is a header file was created with the file I'm using , error : 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64d

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/41355558/8245429