# XCODE Swift 5.0 Frameworks Problems -ObjC and FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, podfile

I'm developing an iOS (>=13.0) app, it's already on the App Store etc...
The problem is that today I've tried to implement the Facebook SDK to permit me to create ad on Facebook and Instagram, I've added the FacebookCore CocosPod and then, as the guide said, I've added on "Other Linker Flags" the flag "-ObjC", since I've added this flag nothing worked, nothing.
I've got several time this error:

> ld: 665 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and all my frameworks files became red.

I've tried to clean up my code, the project, the pod file, I've also removed some pods and the I've put them back because I read some treads where they said it could be a duplicate problem.

After returning to my original podfile I don't have this issue of "duplicate symbols..." but some components of the library (MDCSnackbarManager) don't work and all frameworks files still reds.

I honestly really need your help because I don't know what to do...

Thanks you, please help me.

**UPDATE**

I didn't solve the problem, since all the project seems to be corrupted and nothing works as should...

As I mentioned before I've tried to reload the project from a previous backup on GitHub.

Now I'm doing well, the project works and so I tried to check the differences between this project and the corrupted one, but nothing, they are identical in all shades, even the flags are all the same, I've checked all of them in both project.

I'm now pretty confused about the cause of all these problems, I'll figure out what happened and if I'll find something I will tell you.

If you have any idea I'll read it and try to figure out if it will work.

At the moment what I can tell you is to **NOT** set the flag "-ObjC" and install the FacebookCore pod, don't do that.

Comment: did you try all possible answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298144/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode?

Comment: @KirilS. thanks you for your answer, but I already tried those possibilities, but nothing worked, today I'm going to get a previous backup of the app and then I will go to check what's changed since I've added and removed -ObjC and the FacebookCore SDK