# How to remove one of the cocoa pods plugin from Xcode project

Tags: cocoapods, xcode6.3

anyone know how to remove one of the cocoa pods plugin from Xcode project ? For example, I have installed `afnetworking` and `nyximagekit` in my project. Now, I want to remove `nyximagekit` but keep `afnetwoking`. How to do that ?

Comment: Removing a single pod without updating all other pods, see the `pod install --no-repo-update` answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265655/78336

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to edit the `Podfile` (`$ emacs Podfile` in terminal.app) and remove the line `pod 'nyximagekit'` from it. (`ctrl+x`, `ctrl+s` to save, then `ctrl-x`, `ctrl+c` to quit `emacs`)

Once you did that, run `pod update` and it will remove `nyximagekit` from your project.

Comment: why use the terminal when you could easily open the podfile with any editor?

Comment: terminal will not add anything else to the file when editing, while some rich text editor will

Comment: Thanks u all. it really help.

Comment: @palme Its depend on users convenience. Some one are addicted to terminal and command line. So they preferred terminal rather then text editor. Also, some editors convert quotes to smart quotes.

Comment: i removed pod. after that xcode shows missing file which is in removed pod. what can i do.

Comment: Worked all good. I had to delete a folder in the project and a freamwork in the app setting, though. Oh... and... the `pod update` command updated another framework that fixed a bug I've been researching lately, hehe :D

Answer (score 48):

Remove the pod from your podfile, then run `pod install` again.

Comment: Oh and please user the search function ;) The same question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13759016/1195661

Comment: Wish I could mark your answer as the correct one @palme. I had to read the accepted answer 2-3 times just to get what it was saying. Good grief. thanks for the short, concise and _correct_ answer. :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  "pod update" is used to update all pods to latest version while "pod install" is used to add or remove pods either from the initial pod setup or to update pod additions and removals.  See https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html for details.

Comment: This did not work. It's still in the podfile.lock and project compiles despite library being removed. The hassle of using Cocoapods is simply not worth the small benefit - it's constantly changing, does not work half of the time expect for the first install and completely obscure.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

pictorial information detailed

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that pod line that you want to remove and run pod update !