# Remove only a library from cocoapod project, how i can do?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, braintree

I have an app that holds two libray installed with cocoapods, Braintree and GoogleAnalytics. What i wanna do is remove Braintree from my project. This is my Podfile in the root of my project:

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '7.0'

    target 'MyApp' do

    pod 'Braintree'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'

    end

     target 'MyAppTests' do

      pod 'Braintree'

   end
```

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672868/how-to-remove-one-of-the-cocoa-pods-plugin-from-xcode-project?lq=1) , but maybe i do something wrong. My steps are: Open terminal -> go to root directory of my project -> $ pod update. This returns to me "pod update command not found". What's wrong or what are the correct steps to remove the Braintree library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your pod file in following manner

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '7.0'

    target 'MyApp' do

    #pod 'Braintree'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'

    end

     target 'MyAppTests' do

      #pod 'Braintree'

   end
```

Above file, I have commented the Braintree library. Now you need to execute `pod update` or `pod install`.

As you are facing error of "pod update command not found", you should first install the cocoapods in your mac as guided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37939140/1030951  answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
sudo gem intall cocoa pods
```

And then try pod update again