# How to remove library installed with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to fully remove a library I installed using CocoaPods.

I've removed the entry from my Podfile and called `pod install` from the terminal.

All the library files seems to be deleted but I can still do `import myLibrary` in my iOS Swift project without any build errors.

Why is this so?

Comment: Have you cleaned the project... (deleted derived data)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove or uninstall library previously added : cocoapods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods)

Comment: @l'L'l You save my life.

Comment: @l'L'l That worked. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to completely remove the imports from a previously built project try to `clean` it first:

**In Xcode:**

<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> ( or  `Product` > `Clean` )

This should clear the compiled code from within the projects `release` or `debug` directory:

> `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Project>/Build/(Release or Debug)`

The compiler will often try to use code that it's already compiled during the build process if it can.

Answer (score 1):

Try Cleaning your project.

or use deintegrate

```
 $ gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
 $ gem install cocoapods-clean
```

in your project folder

```
 $ pod deintegrate

 $ pod clean
```

Modify your pod file (delete what you don't want to use anymore)

```
 $ pod deintegrate
```