# Error message 'ld: warning: directory not found for option' while installing and 'library not found for -l' with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, cocoapods, dropbox

I installed IRLDocumentScanner & ObjectiveDropBoxOfficial but impossible to compile because of that error message:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods ?

Comment: I open the Workspace, and not the xcodeproj... I did pod install, pod update, nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always had dependancies problems or update problems using that kind of tools.
I prefer to integrate manually libraries instead of using CocoaPods...

I suggest you remove your pods using this:
[Remove or uninstall library previously added : cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods/35316717#35316717)

and manually install your libraries. It seems more difficult, but you'll save time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to remove CocoaPods and add manually all the files which is more simple. Impossible to find the way to add another pod (ObjectiveDropBoxOfficial) with an existing one (IRLDocumentScanner) without having one thousand problems.
I used that answer to remove it (very well done):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921657/3581620

I will never use CocoaPods anymore.

Comment: Carthage, it's the way to be.